# Jquery if element has class, add class to this element child

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class(active) to a child of an element who has a class (is-active) and does not effect other elements. using jQuery!

```
<ul>
   <li class="nav-item is-active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a><li>
</ul>
```

I'm using this code but it's effect all other elements.

```
if ($(".nav-item").hasClass("is-active")) {
  $('a', this).addClass('active');
}
```

I want to be like this:

```
<ul>
       <li class="nav-item is-active"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Link 1</a><li>
       <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a><li>
       <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a><li>
       <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the selector to target the parent then use `.find()` to get the child.

```
$(".nav-item.is-active").find('a').addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".nav-item").hasClass("is-active")) {
  $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
}
```

You this code it will work

Comment: No, its effect all elements too.

Comment: Please check in your html if you have "is-active" class anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it's into a single selector(which selects a tag within `.nav-item` having `is-active`) and then add class to that.

```
$('.nav-item.is-active a').addClass('active');
```

```js
$(".nav-item.is-active a").addClass('active');

console.log($('ul').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item is-active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a>
    <li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
            <li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
                <li>
</ul>
```

---

**FYI :** In your code `this` does not refer to the element, it may be window object or something else so it won't work. To make it work use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```
$(".nav-item").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("is-active")) {
     $('a', this).addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```js
$(".nav-item").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("is-active")) {
    $('a', this).addClass('active');
  }
})

console.log($('ul').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item is-active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a>
    <li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
        <li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
            <li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
                <li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your element and add class if current element has certain class. Here is working example.

```js
var navlist = $(".nav-item");
$.each(navlist, function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("is-active")) {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('active');
  }
});

console.log($('ul').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="nav-item is-active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 1</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a><li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a><li>
</ul>
```